# Oracle SQL Problems using Variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Having some simple issues here but I've been up for so many hours having trouble focusing so hoping someone else with a fresh head can answer this easy question which I can't seem to find a good answer that works for me in SQL Developer

```
DECLARE
  TEST123 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(APP_ID) INTO TEST123 FROM applicant_credit;
  SELECT * FROM APPLICANT_CREDIT;
END;
```

When I run this which seems easy enough to me I am getting error:

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Also I have a stored procedure I made and works when I send it hard coded numbers, but I need to pass it the count of records from the applicant_credit mentioned in the earlier query which is what I'm actually after. Would the execute stored procedure work the same in the above block as it does outside a block. So should this work??

```
DECLARE
  TEST123 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(APP_ID) INTO TEST123 FROM applicant_credit;
  EXECUTE UPDATE_DECISION(102, 1, 1, 1, 1, TEST123);
  SELECT * FROM APPLICANT_CREDIT;
END;
```

When I run this I get:

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE_DECISION" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ; immediate
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "UPDATE_DECISION" to continue.

Hitting the wall a bit here, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Just for fun, give count(app_id) an alias.  Can't make it any worse.

Comment: There is no `execute` statement in PL/SQL. If `upadte_decision` is a procedure call, then just say, `UPDATE_DECISION(102, 1, 1, 1, 1, TEST123);' There is `execute immediate` for executing SQL constructed at run time or DDL which PL/SQL does not support. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#sthref628

Comment: There is an `execute` command in SQL*Plus and other developer tools for executing a PL/SQL procedure. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#i2697931.

Comment: Found some better examples and read up on using cursors and looping and got it all running. Guess I just needed some sleep. Thanks guys for the responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first sql statement, you are getting that error because you cannot execute a select * statement inside a plsql block in that way. You can either use a cursor or a bulk collect statement or any other way to "redirect" the output of select * into a collection of records.

```
DECLARE
  TEST123 NUMBER;
  cursor c_cur
  is select col_1, col_2 from application_credit;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(APP_ID) INTO TEST123 FROM applicant_credit;
  -- loop through the cursor if required
END;
```

your second sql statement gave an error because you cannot use an execute statement inside the plsql block (unless it is execute immediate which is completely different). So, you can modify the code as follows :-

```
DECLARE
  TEST123 NUMBER;
  cursor c_cur is
  select col1, col2 from applicant_credit;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(APP_ID) INTO TEST123 FROM applicant_credit;
  UPDATE_DECISION(102, 1, 1, 1, 1, TEST123);
  -- loop through the cursor if required
END;
```

some helpful links :-

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/declare.php

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need PL/SQL at all for this unless you are trying to learn it. All can be done with SQL only.

```
DECLARE
  TEST123 NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
  UPDATE_DECISION(102, 1, 1, 1, 1, TEST123);

 -- The outer query is not required, this is only to show you the correct syntax.
  SELECT * INTO TEST123 -- you are selecting from applicant_credit
    FROM 
   (
    SELECT COUNT(app_id) FROM applicant_credit
   );
END;
/
```